# How can I get Object from Table in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have a database table and corresponding class in entity framework. Please tell me how to get data from database and directly set into class object. Here is my code.

It's giving an error like `cannot implicitly convert type Jobportel.Member to Jobportel.DTO.MemberDTO.`

```
  public MemberDTO getMember(String email) {
        MemberDTO member= null;
        using (var db = new jobportaldatabaseEntities()) {

           member=  db.Members.SingleOrDefault(e => e.email == email);

        }
        return member;

    }
```

Comment: Is db.Members a DbSet<MemberDTO> ? I would assume its not.

Comment: Can you show us what `MemberDTO` is?

Comment: no its not. Jobportel.DTO.MemberDTO is a pojo type class and Jobportel.Member is a table entity

Comment: its a bean class containing properties which is corresponding to table columns

Comment: Then you can't assign one to another, you need to get a Member then map it to a MemberDTO. Check out AutoMapper library for quick mapping.